# Get Campaign of a lead view via Metadata (or other) API

Tags: metadata, list-view

Is there any way to get the "Filter By Campaign (Optional)" part of a lead view via the metadata or any other API?

I am trying to convert the metadata of a lead view into an soql query and the campaign of a lead view does not seem to be part of the metadata of a lead view.  I've found the docs for the generic List View at https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listview.htm

this matches what I'm seeing from the metadata api, and I don't see anything about the campaign setting of the lead view.  Is there anyway to get the lead view specific information?